# Replace String with Movieclip

Tags: flash

In my application I have a String like this..

```
var str:String = "The item is [mc]";
```

Here i need to replace the [mc] with MovieClip Object. Is this possible?

But i could not use TLF text,because it increases the file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want this string to appear in a TextField?  You can use the [`<img>`](http://www.justskins.com/forums/using-img-tag-to-116789.html) tag to place a symbol instance from your library.